# grails 2+ url mapping specific rules

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

### **EDIT**

### I had forget a "/" so it is actually working. I don't remove this post as it might be useful for others

I have read many SO answer about grails urlMapping but didn't find any answer that fit my needs.

Let say I have two Domain: `Project` *and* `Contributor`

```
class Project{
   String name;
   String urlName; //is the name converted to url
   static belongsTo = [contributor: Contributor]
}

//a contributor has many Projects, then in the `Project` 
//table I have `contributor_id`
class Contributor{
    String userName;
    static hasMany = [projets: Project]
}
```

My urls looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/frank/frank-s-nice-project/comments
www.mysite.com/bill/bill-s-great-project/comments
www.mysite.com/lucie/lucie-s-awesome-project/comments
```

Which is corresponding to : www.mysite.com/**username/urlName**/comments

`username` comes from **Contributor** Domain.
`urlName` comes from  **Project** Domain

How can I set `urlMappgings.groovy` to always redirect to the same `controller/action` when url matches `"/$username/$urlName/comments"`

I have tried like this but with no success.

```
static mappings = {
    "/$username/$urlName/comments"(controller: 'comment', action: 'index)
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question to make it as accepted answer,

This actually works

```
static mappings = {
    "/$username/$urlName/comments"(controller: 'comment', action: 'index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static mappings = {
    "/comments/$username/$urlName"(controller: 'comment', action: 'index)
}
```

What happens if you replace comments to the first value and make comments then parse username/url ?

The problem I can see with your initial mapping is that username would clash with actual real actions of your project

Comment: did you see the EDIT ? it is actually working. But thanks for the answer